# get the siblingNode value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get a siblings value
here is my code

```
<table class="item-result-table" >
 <tr  class="class-tr">
  <td class="class-td"><label class="class-lbl">labeldata1</label></td>
  <td><label>labeldata2</label></td>
  <td>
    <input type="hidden" name="itmid[]"  value"itmid=something" />
    <input type="button" name="minus-name" class="minus" value="-" />
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I want to get the labeldata1 and I try these

```
$('.item-result-table').delegate('.minus', 'click', function(e) {
        alert(this.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
});
```

results undefined

Any help is highly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using jQuery:

```
$('.item-result-table').delegate('.minus', 'click', function(e) {
    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('label').first().text());
});
```

In case that you want to traverse the DOM using Vanilla JavaScript:

```
$('table').delegate('.minus', 'click', function (e) {
   console.log(this.parentNode.parentNode.children[0].children[0].textContent);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/GFT5a/3/

```
<table class="item-result-table">
    <tr  class="class-tr">
  <td class="class-td"><label class="class-lbl">labeldata1</label></td>
  <td><label>labeldata2</label></td>
  <td>
    <input type="hidden" name="itmid[]"  value"itmid=something" />
    <input type="button" name="minus-name" class="minus" value="-" />
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
    $('.item-result-table').delegate('.minus', 'click', function(e) {
        alert($(this).parent().siblings(':first-child').text());
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should use `$(this)` instead of `this` as it returns a jQuery-compatible object.

I'm fairly sure you want to use `.siblings()` which is described in [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Your posted HTML structure is difficult to test against, seeing as there is no `.item-result-table` class.